# How to convert NSArray ( in string format) to real Array format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray

When i parse one JSON i got following result inside my NSArray

```
(
    {
    category = Allergies;
    group = Allergies;
    name = "Food Allergies";
    option = "";
    subGroup = "";
    type = VARCHAR;
},
    {
    category = Allergies;
    group = Allergies;
    name = "Drug Allergies";
    option = "";
    subGroup = "";
    type = VARCHAR;
},
    {
    category = Allergies;
    group = "";
    name = "Blood Group";
    option = "[{\"id\":1,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"A+\"},{\"id\":2,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"A-\"},{\"id\":3,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"B+\"},{\"id\":4,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"B-\"},{\"id\":5,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"O+\"},{\"id\":6,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"O-\"},{\"id\":7,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"AB+\"},{\"id\":8,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"AB-\"}]";
    subGroup = "";
    type = SINGLESELECT;
}
)
```

Now when i tried to take value for key "option"
`[array valueForKey:@"option"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

i got following result

```
 [{"id":1,"isDefault":false,"additionalOption":false,"optionName":"A+"},{"id":2,"isDefault":false,"additionalOption":false,"optionName":"A-"},{"id":3,"isDefault":false,"additionalOption":false,"optionName":"B+"},{"id":4,"isDefault":false,"additionalOption":false,"optionName":"B-"},{"id":5,"isDefault":false,"additionalOption":false,"optionName":"O+"},{"id":6,"isDefault":false,"additionalOption":false,"optionName":"O-"},{"id":7,"isDefault":false,"additionalOption":false,"optionName":"AB+"},{"id":8,"isDefault":false,"additionalOption":false,"optionName":"AB-"}]
```

but when tried to access "optionName"  like following format

[optionArray valueForKey:@"optionName"];
then i got this error

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x10d8638a0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key optionName.'
```

Please help me to fix this..

Comment: try using enumeration block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using ios 5 or higher, JSON serialization is built in:

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization 
        JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
        options:kNilOptions 
        error:&error];
```

Prior to ios5, you can use SBJSON to achieve the same:

```
NSArray *jsonObjects = [jsonParser objectWithString:string error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
- (NSArray *)convertStringToDictionary:(NSString *)str{
    NSError *jsonError;
    NSData *objectData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData                                               options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

    return json;
}
```

And call like this

```
NSArray *arr =  [self convertStringToDictionary:@"[{\"id\":1,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"A+\"},{\"id\":2,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"A-\"},{\"id\":3,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"B+\"},{\"id\":4,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"B-\"},{\"id\":5,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"O+\"},{\"id\":6,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"O-\"},{\"id\":7,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"AB+\"},{\"id\":8,\"isDefault\":false,\"additionalOption\":false,\"optionName\":\"AB-\"}]"];

NSLog(@"Option Name ---->  %@",[[arr objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"optionName"]);
```

## OUTPUT

**Option Name ---->  A+**

Comment: Why Swift? OP tagged the question with [objective-c].

Comment: can u make it in objc pls

Comment: @Kreiri Converted it in ObjC.

Comment: @Bangalore Please have a look on updated answer.

Comment: @Bangalore Please see updated answer which is working perfect.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFConstantString 0x10eb278a0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key optionName.'

Answer (score 0):

Try using below got to convert to array

```
 NSArray *tmpDayArray=[[NSArray alloc]init];
 NSError *error;
 NSData *dictData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:tmpDayArray options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
 NSString *open_days = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dictData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Try Below code for convert it to NSArray

```
    NSArray * array =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"YOUR STRING"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a complex "object graph." It looks like your outer object is an array, and inside that you have dictionaries.

If `optionArray` is an NSArray then it will give you exactly the error you are reporting if you try to treat it as a dictionary.

Your code:

```
[array valueForKey:@"option"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Is doing that (Although you are using KVC, where you should be using array and dictionary methods directly.)

Your code should look like this instead:

```
NSDictionary* aDict = array[indexPath.row];
NSString *optionString = aDict[@"option];
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any third party like SBJson

```
NSString *optionString  = [[array valueForKey:@"option"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

***Actually you are getting optionString as json String so you have to parse it and then use like this***

```
NSData *data = [optionString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray * optionArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",[optionArray valueForKey:@"optionName"]);
```